What does "Connection" mean in the context of Ngrok?
I have a self hosted miniserver at home, on which I run a tcp tunnel for ssh using an Ngrok client.
On the ngrok usage page https://dashboard.ngrok.com/usage, I'm hitting free-tier limits for several usage statistics related to "Connections". I do not understand how I am hitting these limits as I only ssh into the tcp tunnel roughly once a day.
The limits I sometimes hit are:

Connection Rate: >120 of 120 per minute
TCP Endpoint Connections: >5,000 of 5,000

Can someone help to understand what a "Connection" means in this context, and help me to debug why I might be hitting these limits? I reached out to ngrok support but they were extremely unhelpful.
Log output:

t=2024-10-22T07:57:35+0000 lvl=eror msg="heartbeat timeout, terminating session" obj=tunnels.session obj=csess id=a7ae52e52338 clientid=103e180cfb4ee6395d96eeaf9d0a8eb7
t=2024-10-22T07:57:35+0000 lvl=eror msg="session closed, starting reconnect loop" obj=tunnels.session obj=csess id=f55579472a7c err="session closed"
t=2024-10-22T07:57:45+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to reconnect session" obj=tunnels.session err="failed to dial ngrok server with address "connect.ngrok-agent.com:443": dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout"
t=2024-10-22T07:57:57+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to reconnect session" obj=tunnels.session err="failed to send authentication request: session closed"
t=2024-10-22T07:58:08+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to reconnect session" obj=tunnels.session err="failed to dial ngrok server with address "connect.ngrok-agent.com:443": dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout"
t=2024-10-22T07:58:10+0000 lvl=info msg="client session established" obj=tunnels.session
t=2024-10-22T07:58:10+0000 lvl=info msg="tunnel session started" obj=tunnels.session


How many SSH connections does your SSH server report receiving in its logs? Just because you only make one per day, doesn't mean the rest of the Internet is not making any additional connections...

I guess this is exactly what I'm confused about... looking at https://ngrok.com/docs/errors/err_ngrok_702/ , the page seems to imply that a request does not count as a connection? Meaning that the tunnel would actually have to be authenticated with a correct password before counting as a connection? Also- good point on the logs; I've been clearing them but I've edited my script to keep them. I'll take a look.

That additional note talks about HTTP requests, so it has nothing to do with your non-HTTP tunnel. And no, authentication cannot work that way, as it is necessary to have a connection before you can even send the authentication details.

So I've got some logs from my ngrok server, but it doesn't look like any connection data is logged; I've added the log tail to my post. Thanks for your help!
